# Missing links to responses to comments on nomination posts

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, election, responses

In the *responses* tab in my profile, responses to comments on nomination posts include a working link in the page source, but because there's no title the links are empty and useless.

[image]

When listed in the inbox such posts do have a title, though in this case the link is to the post and not directly to the comment. (Actually, the links in *responses* end up being redirected and also go to the post and not to the comment, but they *try* to go to the comment.)

In Supercollider:

[image]

In Global Profile:

[image]

Comment: Can't we modify these posts to use "2012 Community Moderator Election" as the post's title?

Comment: Also, one can link to individual comments via URL manipulation, but the links can't be generated by the timestamp. And they don't onebox. :S

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moderator Elections functionality: voting UI, commenting and flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361979/moderator-elections-functionality-voting-ui-commenting-and-flagging)

Answer (score 3):

I have created a [script](https://stackapps.com/questions/3470/election-comment-links) that sort of fixes this issue.

It makes the datestamp a clickable link (which works for everyone), and also fixes the stuff in `?tab=responses`.

Note that it has trouble with comments hidden away in the "show X comments" stuff, since comment-linking seems to be only half-implemented on the election page.