# No link text in links to comments that are made on elections on profile pages

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Missing links to responses to comments on nomination posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135225/missing-links-to-responses-to-comments-on-nomination-posts)

I've noticed when browsing through profile pages that links to comments made on an election don't have any link text in them, so can't be clicked on.

For example, the comments made on July 19 and July 17 don't display with a link on [this profile page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/288/chrisf?tab=activity&sort=comments), and the link area has the following HTML code when I look at the code in Firebug:

```
...
<b>
    <a class="question-hyperlink timeline-answers" 
       href="/questions/32144/#comment31410_32144">
    </a>
</b>
...
```