# Wrong title for election related notifications

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, notifications, election

I have some strange titles when I get comment notifications for my nomination on [SO] there stands something like "6|rekire" in the title. I guess that comes from the 6 in the URL https://stackoverflow.com/election/6

I'm pretty sure that this does not happen often however this is a small bug :-)

Edit: The "dublicated" question [Missing links to responses to comments on nomination posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135225/171881) is about links in the web. I'm talking about the app. So that question is related, but not a dublicate at all.

[image: notification title "6|rekire"]

Comment: I think [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135225/missing-links-to-responses-to-comments-on-nomination-posts) is related.

Comment: That looks familiar.

Comment: Re your reason this is not a dupe. I think the *source* of the problem will be the same. That is the core where the error begins will be the same point in the code/scripts, then *all* the messages are sent out *from there* to browser, app, etc. So I think fixing one will resolve the other. I could be talking complete gibberish, so feel free to argue